# Converting basement shower to bathtub

Tags: basement, bathtub

New homeowner here starting his diy life,

I have a gross basement shower I'd like to make into a more normal bathroom experience for guests (the rest of the basement is nicely finished). I'd like to drop in an alcove tub and tile the surrounding walls. But I'm worried about the drain, which is in the concrete. From what I can tell, the thing to do is get a drain above floor rough tub, but I don't understand why this is different than just raising a normal tub a few inches off the ground. I would be very grateful if someone could give me some help and pointers! Thanks

Comment: can you check the wording, maybe expand, it's unclear what you need. Basement tubs are raised when the tub's drain is above the basement's 4" pipe, but that doesn't sound like your situation. the other part would be supporting the tub floor, a need self-apparent.